# How to import a CSV containing a jsonb column type

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to import data into a table with a jsonb column type, using a csv. I've read the [csv specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example) that say any column value containing double quotes needs to:

1. be wrapped in quotes (double quotes at beginning and end)
2. double quotes escaped with a double quote (so if you want a double quote, you must use 2 double quotes instead of just 1 double quote)

My csv column value for the `jsonb` type looks like this (shortened for brevity):

```
"[
   {
      ""day"": 0,
      ""schedule"": [
         {
            ""open"": ""07:00"",
            ""close"": ""12:00""
         }
      ]
   }
]"
```

Note: opened this csv in notepad++ in case the editor is doing any special escaping, and all quotes are as they appear in editor.

[image: PGAdmin Error Message]

Now I was curious about what the `QUOTE` AND `ESCAPE` values were in that PGAdmin error message, so here they are copied/pasted:

- `QUOTE '\"'`
- `ESCAPE '''';""`

To upload to PGAdmin, do I need to use `\"` to around each json token as (possibly?) suggested by that `QUOTE` value in the error message?

I'm using Go's `encoding/csv` package to write the csv.

Comment: Use default options, it seems that you confused a bit with `HEADER`, `QUOTE`, `ESCAPE` etc. Using just `... with (format csv)` should to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can load your file into a json or jsonb typed column using:

```
copy j from '/tmp/foo.csv' csv;
```

or

```
copy j from '/tmp/foo.csv' with (format csv);
```

or their \copy equivalents.

Based on your truncated (incomplete) text-posted-as-image, it is hard to tell what you are actually doing.  But if you do it right, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround I've found is to copy the json data into a text column in a temporary staging table.

Then issue a query that follows the pattern:

```
insert into mytable (...) select ..., json_txtcol::json from staging_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process it through another command before PostgreSQL receives the data, replacing the double double-quotes with an escaped double-quote.

For example:

```
COPY tablename(col1, col2, col3)
FROM PROGRAM $$sed 's/""/\\"/g' myfile.csv$$
DELIMITER ',' ESCAPE '\' CSV HEADER;
```

Here's a working example:

/tmp/input.csv contains:

```
Clive Dunn, "[ { ""day"": 0, ""schedule"": [{""open"": ""07:00"", ""close"": ""12:00""}]}]", 3
```

In psql (but should work in PgAdmin):

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE test (person text, examplejson jsonb, num int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# COPY test (person, examplejson, num) FROM PROGRAM $$sed 's/""/\\"/g' /tmp/input.csv$$  CSV DELIMITER ',' ESCAPE '\';
COPY 1
postgres=# SELECT * FROM test;
   person   |                           examplejson                           | num 
------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----
 Clive Dunn | [{"day": 0, "schedule": [{"open": "07:00", "close": "12:00"}]}] |   3
(1 row)
```

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB (EDB) employee.